# Late payment of estimated taxes

Tags: united-states, income-tax, estimated-taxes

I live in the United States, this is my first year paying estimated income tax and I've missed the first two voucher deadlines.

My question is should I mail them now (late) and send each one separately all at once?  Or lump the total for the three vouchers onto the September voucher (ignoring/amending the amount listed on the voucher)?  Or is there some other way this is typically handled?

I'd imagine this is a fairly common scenario but searching online I was only able to find information about penalties and such, but nothing definitive about how to actually handle missed payments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a payment of the sum of the first two voucher amounts soon as you can: the interest and penalties will be smaller. The interest and penalties don't need to be paid right now; on your 2015 tax return, you should complete Form 2210 (the long version) to figure out how much you owe in interest and penalties. The IRS will offer to do such a calculation (short version of Form 2210 only) for you for free but you will need to pay a little less if you do the math yourself. Whether the difference is worth the additional hassle is up to you. (TurboTax et al will also do these calculations for you).

Comment: Thanks, and sorry if I wasn't clear but this doesn't answer my question.  I'm not asking whether I should pay or when I should pay.  I'm asking **how** I should pay - whether I should use each voucher individually and send seperate payments and if it's ok to use vouchers past their due date, or include it all in one with the current voucher.  Or does it matter at all?  I'm just unclear about the logistics of how to send the payment.

Comment: Make a single payment with one voucher. If you do decide to send two separate payments with vouchers for the two missed payments, send them in separate envelopes instead of trying to save a stamp and putting them in one envelope.